# Hide code (report mode) in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible, and if so how, to generate in a Jupyter notebook a pure report without showing any source code?

The use case and a motivation for this business friendliness (read: no code to read, just results) Our data scientists will mine the data, find patterns and phenomena of interest and then create business friendly visualizations/reports with text, charts and tables, but without any visible source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this [Hide-Input-All](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki/Hide-Input-All) extension would do.

Comment: Link is redirecting now to another place.. I found the following lines of code, which still work: http://blog.quizzicol.com/2016/09/16/hide-input-cells-in-jupyter/

Comment: PS: Unluckily, the export to PDF is then broken with the link in the previous comment